# Add www prefix to a domain in Plesk Parallels

Tags: plesk, prefix, http-redirect, no-www

I have just set up my first domain in plesk (v10 I think? Newest version). I am used to using shared hosting where the www is set up, but upon setting up my domain only http://retapy.com will work, and http://www.retapy.com wont work. I have had a look on here and on other forums and have since changed the domain name in the control panel to "www.retapy.com", but now it doesnt work without the "www." prefix.

I am also wondering, if the domain is set to "www.retapy.com" in the control panel, will I be able to set up other sub domains after?

I would like to use .htaccess:

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^retapy.com
    RewriteRule (.*) http://www.retapy.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But cant do this as it isnt recognising http://retapy.com at all.

What is the best way to set this up?
I read about having the domain set up as just retapy.com (no prefix) and have a "www" folder in the httpdocs folders which is simply a shortcut to the main folder, but I am now completely lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your domain hasn't www DNS record.

Check DNS zone in your domain registrar web site and add "www" cname or a record for domain.

I've checked one DNS server of you domain:

```
[~]# nslookup www.retapy.com NS0.VPS380574-1.LCNSERVERS.COM
Server:         NS0.VPS380574-1.LCNSERVERS.COM
Address:        178.18.126.170#53

** server can't find www.retapy.com.qa.plesk.ru: REFUSED
```

Comment: Thanks, so I add a www DNS record where my domain is registered? Not on the Pleask Host panel? (The domain is registered with someone different to where I have the VPS).

Comment: Yes, exactly. If you will see that your domain served by DNS servers which are can't be managed by your registrar, ask support of your hosting provider about this issue, because I see that DNS servers of your domain are in same place where your hosting is.